# Oracle Package erroring when a table doesn't exist

Tags: oracle, plsql, package

I'm using Oracle 9g at the moment and writing a package, which I'm fairly new to.  I have some procedures in the package that load data into tables from external tables.  It drops those tables first, recreates it with some transformations from the external table, and then creates the indexes for it. I can't just reference the external tables as I need indexes and a few changes to the data.

I then have some other procedures later on in the package that reference these temporary tables to do their work.  It all works fine, except if, when running the procedures in order, the procedure that creates the table gets interrupted after it drops it, but before it creates it.

No if I make a change to the package body it compiles with errors as the later procedure that reference that table inform me that the table does not exist. Nor can I now run any of the procedures due to this validation error.

Can anyone advise of any best practices or how best to do these without getting these validation errors?  Or is there a way to turn off this validation somehow?

Many thanks,
Dan

Comment: Why do you need to drop + re-create the external tables? Only to change the file name? Or does the structure of the external table change?

Comment: Well I suppose I could truncate instead.  I chose to drop and recreate it so that it would make it easier to amend the table later by just modifying the create statement in the procedure and letting it run, and also mainly to create the table if it doesn't exist without writing much extra code.  I thought about changing that to a truncate, but I'm also wondering, for my own training, if there is a way to do this while dropping and recreating them.

Comment: The packages will go invalid when the tables are dropped, but the first attempt to use the invalid packages should result in the system attempting to recompile them and, if successful, allowing the call to proceed. Note that this will only happen if the packaged routine is called from another PL/SQL module or program; if called via OCI/ODBC/whatever, the call will simply fail. In general dropping tables and recreating them is a bad practice, IMO, which only causes problems. You can do this if you wish - but you'll see, it'll all end in tears! :-)  Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks Bob.  They will be called using the Oracle scheduler.  Yes, I was wondering if this was bad practice, as you can't perform such DDL statements without an execute immediate.  Before we used to load data using SQLLdr, but I'd like to move away from using external command line tools. We have CSV files provided on a daily basis, and I need to get them into temporary tables.  If it's bad practice to do so in a package using external tables to temporary tables, and if I can't use SQLLdr,  is there anything else I could do that would be considered good practice?

Comment: The only thing I can think of, I guess (if I want to avoid all DDL), is to use a delete statement to clear down the table before loading the more recent data files.  Though I guess I'd have to rebuild the indexes as well afterwards.

Comment: If you're trying to move away from SQL*Loader, perhaps you could re-work your processing to use [external tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/utility.htm#CNCPT1283). Share and enjoy.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've done.  But I need indexes, which I can't have on external tables.  So instead of querying the external tables directly, I create a new table with them that I can add indexes to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make two packages. One that drops and creates the tables and the other with the data manipulation code. The second package will become invalid once you drop the tables but the first one will still be usable.

Comment: Hmm, yeah.  Then if the second ones starts failing, running the first will fix it.  A shame though.  I take it there's no way to just not run the validation checks once you're confident with the script.

Comment: In these cases dynamic sql comes in handy. But you don't seem to want that for some reason.

Comment: It is actually using dynamic sql.  I pass the create statement into a parameter and run it as a dynamic statement.  It looks like what you suggested above may be the best practice in this case.  Thanks Rene.